# Understanding this delphi method and converting it to C#

Tags: c#, delphi, bit-shift

Could anyone explain to me what this delphi code is doing ?

I know it is shifting some bits but I don't get the purpose ..

```
function PKV_GetKeyByte(const Seed : Int64; a, b, c : Byte) : Byte;
    begin
        a := a mod 25;
        b := b mod 3;
        if a mod 2 = 0 then
            result := ((Seed shr a) and $000000FF) xor ((Seed shr b) or c)
        else
            result := ((Seed shr a) and $000000FF) xor ((Seed shr b) and c);
end;
```

How would I translate that to C# ?

This is what I got so far:

```
private byte PKV_GetKeyByte(Int64 seed, byte a, byte b, byte c)
{
    byte result;
    int aVal = a % 25;
    int bVal = b % 3;

    //IF-IS-MISSING
    if(a % 2 == 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }            
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the explaination on http://www.brandonstaggs.com/2007/07/26/implementing-a-partial-serial-number-verification-system-in-delphi/   shl/shr allow you to drop beginning bits and end bits to work on chunks of the bits.

Comment: @I did I am just trying to implement that in C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe (untested) you want something like...

```
result := ((Seed shr a) and $000000FF) xor ((Seed shr b) or c))
```

goes to

```
result = System.Convert.ToByte((Seed >> a) & 0x000000FF) ^ ((Seed >> b) | c));
```

and

```
result := ((Seed shr a) and $000000FF) xor ((Seed shr b) and c));
```

goes to

```
result = System.Convert.ToByte((Seed >> a) & 0x000000FF) ^ ((Seed >> b) & c));
```

Comment: Can you please explain why is `&&` used in the first part of xor and `&` in second, if they both are called `and` in the delphi code?

Comment: I didnt put &, it was edited to that. I expected it to be &&

Comment: Well, ok. Its, weird, the expressions seems almost same

Comment: For bool operands: In C# '&' and '&&' are almost the same for bool operands. The only difference is that '&&' performs short-circuit evaluation(if the result can be inferred from the first operand, then the second operand is not evaluated), while '&' will always evaluate both its operands.

Comment: Yes but in this example OP can use `&&` instead of `&` but for some reason he edited it to `&`

Comment: Since you are doing bitwise operations, `&&` is **most definitely wrong**. It should be `((Seed >> a) & 0x000000FF) ^ ((Seed >> b) & c)` etc... `&&` is logical "and", while `&` is bitwise "and". In Delphi, there is no difference, and the compiler simply picks what is appropriate. This is not so for most other languages.

Comment: @Mark: no, in this example `&&` is wrong. `& 0x000000FF` is a bitwise masking operation. I'm not sure what `&&` would do, but it would not surprise me if it returned a boolean (ordinal `0` or `1`) value.

Comment: @Mark: just tried. In the VS editor, `0x123456 && 0x000000FF` gets red squigglies and won't compile. `&` is the only correct operator.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Agree. You cannot apply && operator to ints, should be bitwise.

Comment: YO! @RudyVelthuis  havent seen you for ages ... Im Liz the brit!

Comment: @MarkBenovsky et al. Corrected the & issue, and noted that it needed to be convrted tobyte for the result type.

Comment: @BugFinder: Liz the Brit, ey? Long time no see, indeed.

Comment: Beware, it's a trap! `shr` does **not** translate to `>>` because the Delphi shift is a logical shift while the C# shift is an arithmetic shift because its applied to a signed number (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/right-shift-operator) and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Logical_.28Bitwise.29_Operators